# MySQL - Between months (rather than a timestamp)

Tags: php, mysql, date

how would I generate a MySQL query to grab a row that is between a particular month
eg grab row where month is between 01/01 (1st Jan) and 01/06 (1st June)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure, if you want to grab all rows from Jan to June, only the rows until June 1st or all rows from Jan to May. You can use for example:

```sql
[...] WHERE `date_column` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-06-01'
```

which gives you all rows including June 1st.

Use this to get all rows from the full months of Jan to June:

```sql
[...] WHERE YEAR(`date_column`)=2012 AND MONTH(`date_column`) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

(change to `BETWEEN 1 AND 5` for Jan to May)

Comment: Word of warning: if `date_column` is a type with a time component then `date_column BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-06-01'` won't return, for example, a row where `date_column`'s value is `1 June 2012 12:34am`. It'll cut off at 2012-06-01 00:00. This can seem a little counter-intuitive to beginners, so I figured I'd mention it specifically.

Comment: @MattGibson Good Point. Alternative approach: use `DATE(date_column)` instead of `date_column`.

Comment: If you are using a `date_column` with a time component than you can parse the value with `MONTH(CAST(date_time AS DATE))`

Answer (score 4):

If you generate your SQL query in PHP, you can use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
$date = date("Y") . '-' . date("m") . '-01';
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE `date_column` BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
```

(I subtracted one day to exclude the data of the next month first day)

Or you can use [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

```
$month = 5;
$sql = 'SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `date_column`) = ' . $month;
```

Comment: Your first idea isn't so hot because if you take 1 month off of January you end up at Month 0 which doesn't exist.. Instead using the make time commands in PHP would be better wouldn't it?

Comment: @Paul, let me disagree: adding/subtracting intervals correctly handles such cases. In the example you suggest it will return previous year December.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the column in mysql is the right format (date/datetime) you can simply compare (>,<) :

```
SELECT somecolumn 
FROM sometable
WHERE datecolumn >= '2012-01-01' AND datecolumn < '2012-06-01'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: wow - awesome response guys! looks like all your methods should do the trick! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `month()`, `year()` and `day()` functions. So your query would look like something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month(date_field) >= 1 AND month(date_field) <= 6 AND year(date_field) = 2011
```

date_field should be a date or datetime field, if it is a timestamp, you need to use the FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP function so it would look like `month(FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(timestamp_field))`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-06-01';
```