# PHP-MySQL query "SELECT BETWEEN"

Tags: php, mysqli

"SELECT MAX(buildno) FROM `".$tbl."` WHERE( day BETWEEN '$fd' and '$cd') and month='$cm'"

I am using the above query to select data between two days in a particular month , is this the correct way to incorporate PHP variables in SELECT BETWEEN query?

Comment: can you show your full PHP code? 
Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Please copy and paste the code.

Comment: also reading this may help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

Comment: this may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924121/mysql-between-months-rather-than-a-timestamp , there are a LOT of SO questions relating to `between` and dates in MySQL, which questions have you read?

Comment: i have read the above documents but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare two integer values remove single quote for your query.

I never use max() function for performance, so the query is :

SELECT buildno FROM ".$tbl." WHERE ( day BETWEEN $fd and $cd )  AND month=$cm ORDER BY buildno DESC LIMIT 1

For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending variable names as strings, You need to concatenate(like you did with $tbl:

```
"SELECT MAX(buildno) FROM ".$tbl." WHERE day BETWEEN '".$fd."' and '".$cd."' and month='".$cm."'"
```